# python setsockopt what is worng

Tags: python, sockets

what is wrong in that code:

```
def iec104(dst):
     sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
     time = struct.pack('ii', int(2), 0)
     sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVTIMEO, time)

try:
    sock.connect(dst)
except:
    return '', -1


dst = (ip, 2404)
recv, asdu_addr = iec104(dst)
print "ip: {0}, recv: {1}, asdu_addr: {2}".format(ip, 
recv.encode('hex'), asdu_addr)
```

error:

```
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVTIMEO, time)
    File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Is there any bug in "`socket.SO_RCVTIMEO`".
Is a kind of server who wont to lisent and have a timeout
Thanks

Comment: 99% of the time, there is no bug in any code but yours. Not saying this is not that 1%, just that is not where you should start looking.

Answer (score 1):

Struct timeval is 16 bites on 64-bit linux.  More generally, I think you should be using 64-bit integers in your struct call at least on most 64-bit platforms.
It's ugly that this is architecture and OS dependent.
So try 
    struct.pack('ll',int(2),int(0))

Answer (score 1):

Sam Hartman's advice is sound. The absolute dead-simplest way to go about this is;

```
import sys, socket, struct
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
if sys.maxsize > 2**32:
  time = struct.pack(str("ll"), int(2), int(0))
else:
  time = struct.pack(str("ii"), int(2), int(0))
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVTIMEO, time)
```

Note this is not foolproof. `sys.maxsize` may report incorrectly if mixing architectures (32-bit python on 64-bit OS, etc.).